# Why does the method referenced by the onClick layout XML need to be public?

Tags: java, android

So for about 45 minutes I was struggling to understand why my Activity's method was not reachable even though I declared it in the Activity's Layout XML like so:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/lnk_reset_password" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="resetPassword" android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Reset Password" />
```

And my Activity's method signature:

```
private void resetPassword (View v) {
    //logic
}
```

I knew as soon as I got the error that I just need to change the access modifier to "public" but I don't understand why. Does the Layout XML get compiled outside of the scope for my activity?

Thanks,

Comment: I think it's because the `onClick` method being called from outside of your class and then it must be public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mohammad is correct. Private methods may only be called from within the same class, or inner classes of the same class. However, it is Android framework that is calling your resetPassword method, and so it has to be public.

Comment: Is it the generated "R" class that calls my public method?

Comment: No, the R class is just a place to store all the IDs that are generated when the resource compiler processes all of your resource XML files. If you set a breakpoint in your resetPassword method, you can look at the call stack. Your view is processing the touch events when you tap on it, and based on the timing and location of the tap, it decides it was a click, and then it calls the method you've specified. So it's probably the View class itself, or one if its inner classes.

Comment: If you feel motivated to do so, you should download the sources from the SDK manager, and look at all the code that happens when you tap a view. It's pretty cool -- there are timers that are started to verify that it is a tap, and not a long-press, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Because another class needs to be able to invoke it.